# How to test ROR REST api with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Hi i am working on a ROR project with ruby-2.5.1 and Rails 5. I have an api for registration request is as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "password": "passwor",
      "password-confirmation" : "password"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to test this registartion api with cucumber in my rails app.
I have never worked on cucumber what i have tried is:-

my feature file

```
Feature: Registration Endpoint

  Scenario: User registration
    When I send a POST request to "/api/registrations" with the following:
      | email | test@gmail.com |
      | password   | password |
      | password_confirmation   | password |
    Then the response status should be "200"
```

My steps.rb file:

```
When("I send a POST request to {string} with the following:") do |string, table|
  # table is a Cucumber::MultilineArgument::DataTable
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

But i am not sure how to implement steps. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using cucumber instead of RSpec? In all of the projects I have worked on I used cucumber for testing front-end (business logic), i.e. login somewhere, click on the button to display something, edit record. For API/request specs it is easier to use RSpec.

Comment: Yes i have used rspec for unit testing. but the client want cucumber for this api. we gonna call other api for registarion we dont want to use existing registration api.

Comment: Anyway, if this is not urgent, I can help you tomorrow

Comment: @MrShemek are you there?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
When(/^I send a POST request to "(.*)" with the following:$/) do |endpoint, table|
  page.driver.post(endpoint, table.rows_hash)
end

Then(/^the response status should be "(.*)"$/) do |response_code|
  expect(page.status_code).to eq(response_code.to_i)
end
```

In step definition you can always put `binding.pry` to debug and use `save_and_open_page` to display results in a browser. I hope it helps!

Comment: can you please look at my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697138/expected-422-got-200-cucumber-with-rails